# How to properly loop through two files, comparing strings in both files

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to compare two csv files and expecting this output but not able to succeed. Here is my example and code:

File1.csv

```
meNOG00110,9606.ENSP00000349259,1,2364

meNOG06332,9606.ENSP00000344967,1,322

meNOG06773,9606.ENSP00000344961,1,379

meNOG03133,9606.ENSP00000387429,1,2089

meNOG17468,9606.ENSP00000217169,1,298
```

File2.csv

```
meNOG06332,9606.ENSP00000344967,1,322

meNOG00110,9606.ENSP00000349259,1,2364

meNOG00110,9606.ENSP00000357130,1,2419

meNOG00018,10090.ENSMUSP00000027367,1,261

meNOG00018,10090.ENSMUSP00000072852,1,276
```

output.txt

```
meNOG06332  9606.ENSP00000344967    1   322

meNOG00110  9606.ENSP00000349259    1   2364

meNOG00018  10090.ENSMUSP00000027367    1   261

meNOG00018  10090.ENSMUSP00000072852    1   276
```

Code:

```
file1 = open("File1.csv", "rU")
reader1 = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',')

file2 = open("File2.csv", "rU")
reader2 = csv.reader(file2,delimiter=',')

for row2 in reader2:
    for row1 in reader1:
        if row2[1].startswith('9606'):
            if row2[1] == row1[1]:
                print row2              
        else:
            print row2
```

But this code only searches the first row.

Comment: @g.d.d.c That isn't what OP is looking for. He's looking for all N^2 comparisons.

Comment: it looks like his code just prints out `row2`, no matter what happens.  This probably isn't the intention...

Comment: To do it this way, you want to move the opening of file1 inside the first for loop.  When the loop iterates through file1 the first time, it never returns to the beginning of the file for subsequent loops.

Comment: @user587739 What is it you aim to accomplish? Do you want rows in common between the two files?  Do you want only rows in common which contain 9606?

Comment: @Bill I want to search second field of file2 with second field of  file1 and if matches then I want to keep that row. Also I want to keep those rows as it is in which second field starts with 10090.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but because that isn't clear:

if you're looking for overlaps between the two files and you want to compare entire lines, you can make two sets (one for each file) and output the intersection:

```
with open('File1.csv', 'r') as infile1, 
     open('File2.csv', 'r') as infile2,
     open('File3.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    lines1 = set(infile1)
    lines2 = set(infile2)

    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in (lines1 & lines2):
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what format of result you expecting, but for comparing two files you coulf use standard python module:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

You could analyze output, and format as you want

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the two files together:

```
with open(path_a, 'r') as a, open(path_b, 'r') as b:
    for line_a, line_b in zip(a, b):
        print line_a, line_b
```

if the first file is:

```
a
s
d
f
```

and the second file is:

```
q
w
e
r
```

the output would be:

```
a q
s w
d e
f r
```